# Per process drive substitution (windows)

Tags: windows, hook, c++builder, drives

I need to have two processes running on Windows (7), where both of them will have different substitued drives, like:

```
subst P:\ C:\path1
```

...and the second one

```
subst P:\ C:\path2
```

(Why do I need it: Old project files (C++ Builder 5) have the paths to source codes and libraries specified like P:\,L:\,....etc ... and I need them to compile on a buildserver)

How Iam solving it right now:

```
creating net user temporaryuser
paexec/pstools login as temporary user, runing subst and then running the build
```

Is there any other (or better) solution?
-> Even making a systemwide hook that would respond with a substitued drive based on a process-id, is, for me, actually a better solution.

(What cannot be done:
-> C++ Builder 5 does not accept %variables% inside project files, so that is not an option. 
-> Manually substituing drives in project files is dangerous, because the whole thing goes from git and then gets commited again)

Thank you!

Comment: why not set search paths in each project options instead? unless you got hard-coded paths somewhere ... you can do it automated by writing some script that change the project XML file ...

Comment: That is the problem, the paths are hardcoded :( Or nearly-hardcoded, because the old software would not survive the drive letters expanded. My goal is to automate this whole thing, unfortunately ... "it is too old but to make the burden lesser, lets automate it at least" ;) (rewriting to new versions of borland products or compilers is also not acceptable)

Comment: Yeah they not compatible especially if custom components was used ... once I wrote program that read all the sources and change all the `#include`  and `#link` paths from absolute to relative with predefined prefix path to make possible to include framework libs into more manageable include form booth in BCB and AVRstudio. Or to make them work (from MSVC to BCB)  as the SVN source architecture is simply  wrong for me. So you can try to do something similar the code is not that complex ... as it seem from the first look

Comment: The problem is, that changing the paths to relative would make the paths in options SO LONG, that BCB crashes, we tried that :D ... Also we use L:\ as the Library directory substitution... which would be expanded a lot.

Comment: While http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=117 says "local namespace is private to the process", it's incorrect: it's visible to all processes running under the same user account.

Comment: Aww one less option...

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use different accounts.  The namespace isn't local to the user account, it is local to the logon session.  A single user account can, at least in principle, have multiple distinct logon sessions.  In particular, calling `psexec` should give you a separate session even if you use the same user account.  (But multiple simultaneous calls to `psexec` might all be in the same session, I'm not sure.)

Comment: You do need the username and password to generate a new logon session, though, so a temporary account might still be more practical.  Depends on the details of the scenario.

Comment: ... you *could* do this by injecting code into C++ Builder and hooking CreateFile() and other API calls.  That would be tricky, though.  I think your existing workaround would be preferable.

Comment: Why not just `subst` two separate drive letters and then update the projects accordingly? Why does everything have to go through a single drive letter that maps to different locations?

Comment: Harry Johnston -> that is the exact way iam doing it now. It is complicated, since psexec swallows the output and the workaround is getting big :) ... Also Iam actually using temporary accounts (using net user tmp /ACTIVE:no)

Comment: Remy: Why does everything have to go through a single drive letter that maps to different locations? > Because the fuss about automatic modification of project files carries additional precautions for the files to not be commited to git again (reverting the changes, taking care of what happens if the process crashes and the changes do not get reverted) Also it could clow down the process ... we have many project files ... hmm ... Anyway it is a nice idea, considered, that hooking would definitely not be easier :) I promise If we will use Your idea, I will tell you and accept it as an answer :)